# "Missing Translation" during change subscription amount

Tags: payment, bluesnap

6 month ago I worked with Bluesnap API. I wrote method that update Bluesnap subscription amount. Now I return to develop bluesnap connection and up to face with error "Missing Translation" when I use written method.
My method run PUT request by url `https://sandbox.bluesnap.com/services/2/subscriptions/:subscription-id`  with headers

```
Content-Type:application/xml
Authorization:Basic API_AUTH_KEY
```

and request body

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<subscription xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
    <override-recurring-charge>
        <currency>ILS</currency>
        <amount>55</amount>
    </override-recurring-charge>
</subscription>
```

Now instead successful subscription recurring charge change I've got an error

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<messages xmlns="http://ws.plimus.com">
    <message>
        <error-name>UPDATE_SUBSCRIPTION_FAILED</error-name>
        <description>Missing Translation</description>
    </message>
</messages>
```

Does anyone have some ideas how to fix change subscription recurring charge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subscription is probably in a status that cannot be updated.

- Log into your Bluesnap control panel
- Click on Find a transaction from the left side bar
- Choose "Subscription Id" from the list and insert your subscription
  ID and search
- Open any one of the orders
- Locate the "Subscription Information" box
- Check the "Status" field in that box. If it's anything other
  than  Active, then  that's why.

Let me know what you see!
That error is weird though and I would report it to Bluesnap if I were you

Comment: You're right. Subscription has status "Payment reached max charge". But what is strange that when I get Subscription info by API it returns to me status A (Active) without any notification. In my case `<override-recurring-charge>
        <currency>ILS</currency>
        <amount>11370.00</amount>
    </override-recurring-charge>`. Is it too high value? And where I can see limitation?

Comment: I think it's defined in the contract if you open it in the control panel? I'm not sure. I moved to their more recent subscriptions API which is much simpler than this one. I create the plans via API (you cannot manage or see them in the UI). [This](https://developers.bluesnap.com/v2.0/docs/create-subscription) is what I use.

Comment: Looking at url their extended payment API must be recent /v3.0/ if compare with payment API /v2.0/ . But 6 month ago I didn't see payment API JSON /v2.1/ . Which of this APIs are most stable and flexible?

Comment: The Extended API requires a lot of information about the shopper, so it depends if your checkout page collects all of that or not. The Payment API is newer and doesn't require a lot of information. I recommend you contact Bluesnap to ask about which is more flexible according to your needs.

Answer (score 1):

The version you see is the documentation’s and not the API. 
If you want only to use Bluesnap for payments and not for managing products/contracts then Payment API is the best option for you.

I point you to this URL that explain the various options of integrating with BlueSnap:

https://support.bluesnap.com/docs/which-bluesnap-solution-do-i-need